# Merge each value in one colum

Tags: grafana

I want each value just use one column to show
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbkGL.png)

to like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlbF9.png)

Comment: Don't just use same placeholder `enter image description here`.Please add valid Text to image in if you creating hyper link for the image.

Comment: Provide more information: what datasource is used, how data queried, what transformation applied at grafana.